# Iterating Through a List of Functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, methods

Let's say I have the following code:

```
string = "XxXxXx"
print(string.lower())
print(string.upper())
```

How could I use a list instead along the lines of:

```
string = "XxXxXx"
list = [lower(), upper()]
for i in list:
    print(string.i)
```

Obviously the code above does not work at all and the problem I'm working on is way more complicated. But if I could make the example above work, it would really take care of my problem!

Comment: Beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). In example code it's not a big problem, just a bit confusing, but in more involved code, it's better to use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `L` or `lst`. Cf. [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](/q/31087111/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

Functions (and methods) are first class objects in python. You can therefore store them in a list just like you would anything else.

If you want to be able to apply the functions to arbitrary strings, use the unbound function objects in the class:

```
string = "XxXxXx"
func_list = [str.lower, str.upper]
for i in func_list:
    print(i(string))
```

If you want to only apply the functions to your special string, you can store the bound methods in a list instead:

```
string = "XxXxXx"
func_list = [string.lower, string.upper]
for i in func_list:
    print(i())
```

In both cases, the `()` operator is what calls the function. The function name by itself is a reference to the object. In the first case, the `.` operator does not do anything surprising. In the second case, since you invoke it on an instance of a class, it binds the function object in the class to the instance, creating a bound method that has an implicit `self` argument.

Comment: @AlexReynolds. List is not a keyword, it's the name of a builtin class, but your general thought is correct. Will fix momentarily.

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, call it that, but don't use keywords to name variables unless you want headaches down the road.

Comment: @AlexReynolds. Yes, you are right, but using correct terminology is important too. You can't really be meaningfully pedantic about one but not the other.

Comment: @Alex It really isn't a keyword. [Keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) can't be assigned to, like `None`. [It's a builtin type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).